# jdbc db2 SocketTimeoutException on connecting to database

Tags: java, jdbc, db2-luw

I am trying to connect to a remote db2 database using the db2 jdbc drivers and am getting a sockertimeout error. I have deployed to two different machines and on the second machine I don't get the error. I'm thinking that this could be something to do with a network connection to the box that my db2 database is on.

Can anyone help me with ways that I can try and debug this error. So far the only think I can come up with is to use tracert hostname to compare the number of hops on the box that the connection works and on the one that it does not.

thanks

```
[11/5/14 14:22:46:537 EST] 0000d296 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:413)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:274)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:261)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:389)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.y.run(y.java:34)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:241)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.xb.a(xb.java:390)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.xb.<init>(xb.java:79)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.a.x(a.java:265)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.b.a(b.java:1781)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bb.a(bb.java:394)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bb.<init>(bb.java:354)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.b.<init>(b.java:314)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:174)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:572)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:196)
        at com.myer.epostools.db.DBUtility.createConnection(DBUtility.java:18)
        at com.myer.eposweb.dao.BaseDAO.getConnection(BaseDAO.java:36)
```

Comment: Is the server DB2 LUW, DB2 z/OS, or DB2 for i?

Comment: I'm not sure actually, it's installed on a Linux server

Comment: I'm on db2 version DB2/LINUXPPC 9.1.6. However the boxes I am connecting to are windows boxes on the same db2 version.

Comment: OK that rules out driver issues if you had been connecting to DB2 for i.

Comment: I found out that this was a network problem. We found that when we telnetted from the app server to the remote db server of port 51000 we had mixed timing results. The root cause was that the traffic was being interecepted by the company's network traffic filter. We fixed this up and it fixed my problem. thanks!